# How are loaded Javascript contents

Tags: javascript, html, function, datepicker

I would have a datepicker that is able to set the current date automatically
So, i searched in internet and i found this solution:

```
$(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#DataModifica").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    })
    $("#DataModifica").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});
```

I wanted to change it and i wrote:

```
$(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#DataModifica").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        setDate: currentDate
    })
});
```

but it didn't work. So, how are loaded the elements into a javascriot function?

Comment: So why are you not using the working solution?

Comment: i ' m using the working solution but i want to understand where i failed in my code

Comment: `setDate` is not a option but a method of the Datepicker Widget. You could set a default date: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: Perfect jolmos! this is the answer i wanted! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#DataModifica").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        "setDate",: currentDate
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery UI's DatePicker, then the reason is that `setDate` is a method that's called afterwards not at initialisation. To initialise with a specific date you'd need to use `defaultDate` instead, e.g.

```
$(function () {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $("#DataModifica").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: currentDate
    })
});
```

(see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate for more info)

Answer (score 0):

hope this may be helpfull

here `cd` is the current date

```
$(function() {
      var cd = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());
}
```